# Error installing forecast package on R (2020)

Tags: r

Trying to learn more about forecasting in R but I can`t seem to find a way to install the forecast package and it is really frustrating. Any help is much appreciated. I have tried

```r
install.packages("forecast")
install.packages('forecast', dependencies = TRUE)
```

but none work

when I run install.packages('forecast') it gives me this error several times

```
Error in readRDS(file) : 
  cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 4.0.2; need R 3.5.0 or newer
```

followed by

```
* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in readRDS(pfile) : 
  cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 4.0.2; need R 3.5.0 or newer
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/David/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/ggplot2'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/David/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/ggplot2'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\David\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQrZOJI/downloaded_packages/ggplot2_3.3.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
```

--- then this error when I run library("forecast")

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’ in readRDS(pfile):
cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 4.0.2; need R 3.5.0 or newer
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘forecast’ was built under R version 3.4.4

Comment: What errors do you get when you try to install it?

Comment: Try `install.packages("ggplot2")`. Seems odd that it wasn't installed. Check for any error messages. Also it seems odd that your forecast package was build under a very old R version (3.4.4). What version of R are you actually running?

Comment: @David You try and update your R to the latest version.

Comment: Hello, @MrFlick I tried Installing it but It didn't solve the problem. I am currently running [64-bit] R-3.4.2 maybe that`s an issue? I tried updating it but I still have the same version

Comment: @Ash I just updated to version 4.0.2 and it is still giving me problems

Comment: @r2evans hello, I am new to this, is there any way I can send you the list of errors. I believe it will exceed the text limit on these comments

Comment: Really, the best way for this is to [edit] the question and add them there in a [code-block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Make sure to include more than you had in that (since-deleted) comment, since it seemed to miss something. Often the culprit includes something from `gcc` or about a linker problem.

Comment: @r2evans done! hope that helps

Comment: The error messages indicates that you still use `R` 3.4 (see `win-library/3.4`). Make sure that you've updated to 4.0.2 and that RStudio (or the R Gui) detected and uses the new R version

Comment: If you think you updated to R version 4.0.2, this error doesn't reflect that update. (I don't have many ideas regardless, sorry ...)

Comment: @DavidShrem Do you have the `ggplot2` library installed? Or are errors coming up while installing the `ggplot2` package?

Comment: @Ash it is getting really wierd. I can install packages like lattice with no issue but getting problems with installing packages like quantmod and forecast. all giving similar problems ```library(quantmod)`` to ``Loading required package: TTR
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘TTR’ in readRDS(pfile):
 cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 4.0.2; need R 3.5.0 or newer
Error: package ‘TTR’ could not be loaded ```

Comment: @r2evans I updated R yesterday with the following code ```install.packages("installr")
library(installr)
updateR()``` maybe that can help?

Comment: I never use `installr` so I don't know (I just update the "normal" OS-way).

Answer (score 0):

So at first, the updateR didn't work so what I did was I uninstalled everything associated with R and Rstudio and installed everything back again. I believe I lost the packages that I had installed over time but now I am having no issues installing any package

to install back properly I used the following video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-RrkJQQYqY

I know it is probably not the best idea to do what I did but desperate times require desperate measures. Thanks for all the comments and help!